# Can I extend a generic type? in F#

Tags: f#

I have a DU representing error states:

```
type ExchangeError =
    | NoError
    | ServiceUnavailable
    | HttpError                 of HttpStatusCode * string
    ...
```

and I have one return type used everywhere:

```
Result<'a, ExchangeError>
```

Is there a way for me to add a method to that type that would work like this pseudo-solution:

```
type Result<'a, ExchangeError> with

    member this.GetOrFail
        match this with
        | Ok data -> data
        | Error e -> failwith $"error: {e}"
```

to be used like this:

```
let result = myData.GetOrFail
```

I find myself typing this over and over when doing exploration code and I don't care about handling errors, etc; I want either a result or stop at that point.
So, I thought a helper method may be useful.

But how can this be achieved?

Answer (score 3):

There's nothing in `GetOrFail` that relies on the error type, so you can just make a generic extension:

```ml
type Result<'a, 'err> with

    member this.GetOrFail =
        match this with
        | Ok data -> data
        | Error e -> failwith $"error: {e}"
```

But if you really want this extension to apply only to `Result<'a, ExchangeError>`, you can do it with a [C#-style extension member](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/type-extensions#extension-methods):

```ml
open System.Runtime.CompilerServices

[<Extension>]
type Extensions() =
    [<Extension>]
    static member GetOrFail (res : Result<'a, ExchangeError>) =
        match res with
        | Ok data -> data
        | Error e -> failwith $"error: {e}"
```

In this case, you have to invoke it as a method, rather than a property, but I figure that's still good enough.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can add extension methods to a partially constrained generic type like that. Probably the best way is to just use a function:

```
module ExchangeError =

    let getOrFail (x: Result<'a, ExchangeError>) =
        match x with
        | Ok data -> data
        | Error e -> failwith $"error: {e}"

let result = getOrFail myData
```

Comment: You actually can do it with a C#-style extension member. See my answer.

Comment: Interesting, I'll have to keep that in mind.